# Conectarse a una base de datos desde java sin escribir en el codigo fuente las sentencias SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

El otro día un profesor nos comentó que introducir sentencias SQL dentro del código de nuestra aplicación Java era una mala practica.

Actualmente yo lo hago a través de la librería JDBC y escribiendo las sentencias directamente en el código como podéis ver en el ejemplo siguiente.

```
    String duracion = "14 mn";
    String SQLQuery = "insert into ejemplo(a,b,c,d)"
            + "values(?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        this.abrirConexion();

        PreparedStatement stm=this.getConexion().prepareStatement(SQLQuery);

        stm.setInt(1, 14);
        stm.setInt(2, 45);
        stm.setString(3, "Esto es un ejemplo"); 
        stm.setString(4, duracion);

        stm.executeUpdate();

        this.cerrarConexion();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

La duda es, si es correcto que esto es una mala práctica, cual es la mejor manera de recibir y enviar datos desde una base de datos.

Un saludo.

Comment: Otra opcion es usar [hibernate](http://hibernate.org/)  te olvidas de la mayoria de las consultas SQL

Comment: Otra opción son los Stored Procedure o usar Vistas. En cuanto a si es o no una mala práctica, en general si. Todo va a depender de lo expuesto que esté tu código y el ambiente de uso. Si tu profesor (tutor) te aconseja que no lo hagas, es por un motivo. Hay quien dice que mientras evites el SQL injection todo va bien, sin embargo exponer una consulta en tu código puede dar una idea de la estructura de la base de datos. Ya por allí puedes pensar en un fallo, llámalo de seguridad o de privacidad. Pero es un fallo.

Comment: Aunque [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) está enfocada a PHP, en realidad sirve para todos los lenguajes, te recomiendo leerla

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por los comentarios. Me han servido de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así está correcto. Estás previniendo las [inyecciones SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) con `PreparedStatement`.

Lo que no es recomendado por seguridad es hacer algo similar a esto:

```
 String sql = "Insert INTO ejemplo values(a,b,c,d) values(14, 45, Esto es un ejemplo,"+duracion+")";
 conn = //conexion bd
 Statement st = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias :D